# PDO Merging Results in to One Array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, array-merge

I have a query result. Here is my code.

```
$P = new Product();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($P->get_product_image_path(1));
echo "</pre>";
```

In Product Class i have this function.

```
public function get_product_image_path($productid){
       $sql = "SELECT picture FROM ".PREFIX."product_picture WHERE product_id = :id";
       $this->query($sql);
       $this->bind(':id', $productid);
       if ($this->rowCount() > 0)                
            return $this->queryResults();
       else 
           return NULL;

   }
```

Here is my database class functions

```
    public function query($sql)
    {
        return $this->_sql = $this->getPdo()->prepare($sql);
    }


    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
          switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
              break;
            case is_bool($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
              break;
            case is_null($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
              break;
            default:
              $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
          }
        }
        $this->_sql->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }



    public function execute(){
        return $this->_sql->execute();
    }



    public function queryResults(){
          $this->execute();
          return $this->_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
```

The result is returning

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [picture] => 1328630682_1_xl.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [picture] => 1328630696_1_xl.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [picture] => 1328630689_1_xl.jpg
        )

)
```

But i want to merge results like that

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1328630682_1_xl.jpg
        [1] => 1328630696_1_xl.jpg
        [2] => 1328630689_1_xl.jpg
    )
```

How can i do that. I'm new on PDO that's why i couldn't do it.

Answer (score -1):

1. get rid of your database class.
2. do not extend your product class from database class.
3. use PDO to get an array in the desired form

here it goes

```
public function get_product_image_path($productid)
{
    $sql = "SELECT picture FROM ".PREFIX."product_picture WHERE product_id = :id";
    $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($productid));
    return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
}

$pdo = new PDO(...);
$P = new Product($pdo);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($P->get_product_image_path(1));
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a new database class function

```
public function queryColumn($index = NULL){
    $index = (isset($index)) ? intval($index) : 0;
    $this->execute();
    return $this->_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,$index);
}
```

And i edited my function

```
public function get_product_image_path($productid){
       $sql = "SELECT picture FROM ".PREFIX."product_picture WHERE product_id = :id";
       $this->query($sql);
       $this->bind(':id', $productid);
       if ($this->rowCount() > 0)                
            return $this->queryColumn();
       else 
           return NULL;

   }
```

Hence, i manage to merging arrays.